# Change Binary String to Integer Through Every two character separation

Tags: java, regex

```
String startingp="1000000100001110010100";

 String start =java.util.Arrays.toString(startingp.split("(?<=\\G..)"));
 start = start.replaceAll("\\p{P}","").trim(); //trim coz of the bracket
 int foo=Integer.parseInt(start, 2);
 System.out.println("Splitstart:" + start);
```

**I need to separate every two digits of startingp which is the 
  binarystring :example 11 00 01 and also change them to integer value. But I receive error as result. Care to explain for me what is wrong with the code**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10 00 00 01 00 00 11 10 01 01 00"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)

Comment: ... just don't add the spaces. `parseInt` doesn't handle them.

Comment: Nope .I already try that before still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like so :

```
String startingp = "1000000100001110010100";
List<Integer> result = Arrays.stream(startingp.split("(?<=\\G..)"))
                .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s, 2)) // parse each string in the array
                .collect(Collectors.toList());    // collect the result in the end
```

**Outputs**

```
[2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0]
```

Where each int is the equivalent to one of :

```
[10, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 11, 10, 01, 01, 00]
  2   0   0   1   0   0   3   2   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite clear: `"10 00 00 01 00 00 11 10 01 01 00"` is not a string that `parseInt` can parse to an int.

It's unclear why you want to separate the digits into pairs first. Just parse `startingp` directly:

```
String startingp="1000000100001110010100";
int foo=Integer.parseInt(startingp, 2);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/UvgY8H)

If you mean that you want to parse the *pairs* into ints, you need to apply it to each element in turn:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.stream(startingp.split("(?<=\\G..)"))
        .map(p -> Integer.valueOf(p, 2))
        .map(Object::toString));
    .collect(joining(" "))
```

Comment: No..i dont want to change the whole startingp to integer..i need to change every two digits of the binary to integer since it is actually a pair of chromosome value. Every  pair has different meaning

Comment: @FarahainaIdris if that's what you want to do, how do you expect `int foo=Integer.parseInt(start, 2);` to do it? That's saying "parse `start` into *1* `int`". If you expect multiple values, the result would have to be something that can hold multiple values, like an array, list, stream etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse every 2 characters to its decimal representation, you need to split the string again on spaces and parse every 2 characters. So you need a for loop:

```
ArrayList<String> convertedToDecimal = new ArrayList<>();
for(String twoChars: start.split(" ")){
    convertedToDecimal.add(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(start, 2)));
}
```

This ArrayList can then be joined to create the String you want with `String.join("", convertedToDecimal.toArray(new String[convertedDecimal.size()]))`

Answer (score 0):

With plain old java:

```
    List<Integer> intNums = new ArrayList<>();
    String startingp="1000000100001110010100";
    for(int i=0; i<startingp.length() - 2; i+=2){
        String strNum = startingp.substring(i,i+2);
        Integer intNum = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
        intNums.add(intNum);
    }
    System.out.println(intNums);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem at this line ;

```
int foo=Integer.parseInt(start, 2);
```

Because here `start` param is equal to `10 00 00 01 00 00 11 10 01 01 00`. If you analyze the `parseInt` function, you can see this *comparasion* on this string to be a ***smaller*** than `2` for all chars of `string`. So in your parameter some `space` , this is not ***valid***.

To resolve this, split with space to get all two combination in string. Do it like this ;

```
String startingp = "1000000100001110010100";
String start = java.util.Arrays.toString(startingp.split("(?<=\\G..)"));
start = start.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").trim(); //trim coz of the bracket
final String[] splittedStart = start.split("\\s+"); // parse with blank 
Arrays.stream(splittedStart).forEach(s -> System.out.println("Split start: " + Integer.parseInt(s, 2))); // to print.
```